# accessing doubled elements with Javascript in Media Queries

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm using JavaScript to access HTML elements with GetElementById.
Now I changed the HTML/CSS to use Media Queries for large/small screens and by that I needed to double some of the elements. Double, because I want to display and control (javascript) certain elements in different positions of the screen, depending on if they are shown on a PC or on a Smartphone.

Problem, now I can't use getElementById anymore since that must be unique.
But I don't want to use getElementsByName, since that requires lots of changes on the Javascript and basically produces the same amount of code as if I just use different Ids for all elements for each Media Query. Are there better ways?

e.g.
now (with getElementById) - Setting one icon:

```
document.getElementById("idIcon1").innerHTML = '<src="/Images...>';
```

with getElementsByNames - Setting the same Icon (used twice on HTML, each in its Media Query section):

```
document.getElementsByName("Icon1")[0].innerHTML = '<src="/Images...>';
document.getElementsByName("Icon1")[1].innerHTML = '<src="/Images...>';
```

in **HTML**:

```
<div class="screenLarge">
  <div name="idIcon1" class="icon1_Large"></div>
  ...
</div>
<div class="screenSmall">
  <div name="idIcon1" class="icon1_Small"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

(The classes ScreenLarge / ScreenSmall are Display:none, depending on the Screen size.)

If I use the getElementsByName, that produces 2 lines of code in JS (for [0] and [1]). But that is pretty much the same thing, as if just use two different IDs, one for small and one for large screens.

Any idea is welcome...

thanks
hbi

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea below, you can make that even a bit more generic, e.g.

```
function myFunction(name, prop, value) {
    var el = document.getElementsByName(name);
    var i;    

    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      switch (prop) {
        case "innerHTML": el[i].innerHTML = value; break;
        case "color": el[i].style.color = value; break;
        ...
        default: break;
     }
  }
}
```

and then call the function like this:

```
  myFunction("idActVerb", "innerHTML",  "-");
  myFunction("idActVerb", "color", "blue");
```

perhaps not the most beautiful code but it serves my purpose, so I'll give it a try :-)

thanks partypete and Kamil

Answer (score -1):

What if you created a function that you called for every different set of elements with matching names? That way you'd only have to call it once for each pair.

```
myFunction(document.getElementsByName("idIcon1"), '<img src="/Images...">');

function myFunction(el, inner) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
       el[i].innerHTML = inner;
    }
}
```